# How to define activities in different packages

Tags: android

I have splitted my application into several `packages`. Some of my classes which extends `Activity` is located under `com.tmt.app` and another `Activity` is in the package `Dialogs`. Both packages is located under the `src` folder, I noticed that in my Manifest file I specify the package name like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tmt.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

which indicates that this manifest is relevant for the package `com.tmt.app` The relevant class is defined like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PasswordDialog"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Which indicates that the class `PasswordDialog` is in the package `com.tmt.app`

How can I specify that this class is located under the package `Dialogs` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two packages, like `com.one` and `com.two`. Your manifest looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.two"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

.......

<activity
        android:name="com.one.a"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".b"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

You will need to use the fully qualified name to reference an Activity from outside the package.

OR

If the second package is a subpackage like com.one and com.one.two, you'll use:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.one"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

.......

<activity
        android:name=".two.a"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".b"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your activity  `android:name=".PasswordDialog"` like this then it consider as the current package activity where package is declare in root of manifest .

When you have to declare your activity in another package then you have to  declared your activity in menifest as below.

```
<activity
        android:name="YourAnotherPackageName.PasswordDialog"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Dialogs.PasswordDialog"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the whole path of the package. Example :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tmt.Dialogs.PAsswordDialog"
        android:theme="@style/AboutTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the manifest select application tab in application node  select add activity then you will get the list of available activities select from them thats the best method and hazzle free